# How can I multi-boot many Linux distros and Windows on the same USB drive?

Tags: linux, windows, usb, live-usb, multiboot

I am in the process of making a "toolkit" so I can use when I need, wich consists of many Linux distros, Windows 10 and Hiren's BootCD.

I know I can make the Linux part with [Multi Boot USB](http://multibootusb.org/) but I don't know how to add the Windows stuff in the same drive. Thanks for your help.

This is also my first time posting here, if there is a better place for this, please notify me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns a Windows install

Comment: Really? That takes this off from this community? That doesn't even make any sense!

Comment: I am voting this question for leave open, because interoperability of Linux with other systems is *per definitionem* on-topic.

Comment: @RodrigoGameiro There is a continuous tension in the communities, where is the limit where a question becomes off-topic. You can read more about the phenomenon [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deletionism_and_inclusionism_in_Wikipedia). Get to reputation 15 ASAP, so you will be able to use the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com). If you got it, ping me on the chat and we will talk.

Answer (score 1):

First, the most important thing: *you can do it.*

Windows configurability is catastrophic, so the best if you start with a Windows pendrive and you extend it with a secondary Linux partition and with a more intelligent bootloader.

Thus, the required steps:

1. Get your Windows boot pendrive from anywhere. In the details, for example https://superuser.com can be your friend.
2. It is very important, that the Win should be on the first partition of the USB disk. W$ has the "nice" feature, that partitioned pendrives can see only their first partition on it, and no more. There is no workaround against it without major w$ kernel hacks, what is impossible.
3. So you have a dual-partition pendrive, on its first partition should be the win, and the Linux on the second.

The BIOS will see the pendrive as 0x80 hard disk. But if you plug in to your devel machine, it will be some alternate hard disk (most probably, `/dev/sdb`). It can have a little trouble with the bootloader install:

#### LILO

In LILO, you can predefine for the disks, below which bios disk number will they be visible, on this way in the `lilo.conf`:

```
disk = /dev/sda
  #bios = 0x80
  inaccessible

disk = /dev/sdb
  bios = 0x81
  #inaccessible
```

The disadvantage of the Lilo is that you have to understand its exact workings much better to avoid the mystical "won't work" problems.

Lilo, as the BIOS tools in general, doesn't see partitions, it reads only a map of sectors. This map can be anywhere on the pendrive.

#### Grub

As far I know, grub suspects the boot install drive will be 0x80, what is clear. However, my experience is that the probability of mystical "won't work"-like problems are in the case of grub much higher, despite that it can - theoretically - read into the filesystems on the boot device.

The solution requires an in-depth reconfiguration of grub on a deeper level as the `update-grub`, `grub-install` scripts today do. Prepare for a lot of mystical problems.

#### Syslinux/Isolinux

Syslinux wants a FAT or ISO fs for boot, none of them are possible for a recent windows install (wanting NTFS), thus it probably falls out, because it contradicts with the Windows requirement that it wants to boot from the first partition. You may be able to use syslinux in a highly uncommon configuration (3 partitions: 1: windows NTFS, 2: linux ext4, 3: boot fat).

---

I personally would solve such a task on this way:

1. I would get a win-only pendrive image from somewhere
2. I would get an ubuntu live cd
3. I would merge the two that the win would go into the first partition, the Linux into the second,
4. I would throw away the syslinux of the ubuntu live cd and I would boot it with LILO (the syslinux config contains the info, how exactly should you boot the Ubuntu from the pendrive).
5. Finally I would talk my boss/customer to accept that the pendrive will be readonly. If it doesn't work or I would want a perfect solution, then I would clone a minimal ubuntu system. Btw, read-write usable windows system is probably impossible from a pendrive, only install/live/rescue kits are existing. With Linux you can do it, but it requires bonus work. Alternativelly, instead the ubuntu livecd I would suggest to give a try to knoppix.

Comment: A more detailed description depends on your actually used bootloader.

Comment: I want to thank you a lot for answering my question, and I will try it in the future.
Also, just wanted to note that this isn't for a customer, but for myself.

Answer (score 0):

try [www.easy2boot.com](http://www.easy2boot.com)

Unlimited Windows ISOs, linux ISOs, VHDs, WIMs, .IMA, linux+persistence, Secure boot UEFI, etc.

The USB stick can be prepared using linux or Windows.